# ASP .NET MVC html.textbox not returning value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.textbox

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection form)
    {

        string name = form["firstname"];
    }
```

View:

```
@Html.TextBox("firstname", null, new { style = "width:100px" })
```

I am entering some text into the textbox and submitting the form but when I break the program at the string declaration, the name variable is empty, even though when I hover over form["firstname"], the value I entered in the textbox appears in Visual Studio.

How can take the text entered in the textbox and place it into a string variable?

Comment: Did you surround your View with Form element? If not you will need to place it inside your form in order to pass it back to the server. Could you provide more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most likely this happens to you because this variable is not used anywhere in the code later on. If it sees that the variable is not used later, is it smart enough not to care about assigning a value to it.

to see if it works simply add this code after yours:

```
string s = name;
```