# Create a folder with a name typed by user in textbox ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, textbox

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC 4.

I'm able to create a folder with a hardcoded name using Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:/") in my controller, but what I need to do is have the user type the desired folder name into a textbox, and pass that information to the CreateFolder method in the Controller.

Here's the method:

```
public ActionResult CreateFolder(String newFolderName)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\..." + newFolderName);

        return View();
    }
```

In my view I need a textbox for the user to define the desired folder name, and a button that creates the folder with the selected name.
How should I handle this?

I've tried some suggestions from the web, but can't seem to get it going.

Comment: _'I've tried some suggestions from the web'_ ... like what? Lest we reiterate. Furthermore, it is entirely unclear exactly what your problem actually is.

Comment: My spidey sense is going off about the fact that you're trying to tightly couple a web concept like MVC w/ a winforms concept like File Directories... Not saying there aren't some applications for it, but it makes me pause

Comment: @Rikon: Directories are not a WinForms concept.  However, this is probably a bad idea and may be a security hole.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Hello, I've tried integrating something akin to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064481/asp-net-mvc-4-calling-method-from-controller-by-button and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167635/asp-net-mvc-html-textbox-not-returning-value as well as a number of others.   Apologies if I've been too vague.  It was in the hope of seeing how others might handle it from a fresh perspective.

Comment: To clarify, I'm new to MVC as a whole.  I'm experimenting with some simple applications to get my bearings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View:

```
@using Folder
@using ( @Html.BeginForm( "CreateFolder", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post) )
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.FolderName)
    <input type="submit" id="btnCreateFolder" value="Create Folder" />
}
```

Model:

```
public class Folder
{
    // other properties
    string FolderName {get;set;}
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateFolder(Folder model)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\..." + model.FolderName);
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it's working perfectly now, and I've got a better understanding Controller - View communication.